# What should I do to run my javascript code on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a javascript code that rotate the canvas. The script is working fine on my Firefox browser. But when I open it in chrome, it looks too bad to see on it. **What should I do to write the browser compatible javascript?** My code is about 1000+ lines So **How could I Find the functions which not support the browser rendering?**
Please If anyone have other suggestion also then please post it.

Comment: try debugging with chrome console (F12)

Comment: This question cannot be usefully answered. If you can create a [minimal, self-contained functioning example](http://sscce.org) of the code you're having trouble with and post it to your question (possibly also with a link to a live site like http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net), people may be able to help you.

Comment: Best solution: install all browsers and test the page

Comment: @Alex    OK , I checked my code in all browsers already. But How could I get the function which is not support the other browsers. Anyone have trick for that??

Comment: You are not following best practices while writing your JS code, otherwise the code should work just fine in each browser. Moreover you can achieve rotation by the use of packaged in-browser rendering engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BrowserSwarm](http://www.browserswarm.com/) which is a project started by Microsoft aims to test JavaScript project compatiability for major browsers. It's easy to use and one-way to connect GitHub.

But for small project or specific problem, open console and start debugging is prime choice.

Comment: Can you clarify "prior" choice. I assume you mean "prime"? or "priority"? or "premier"?

Comment: @Gray sorry for my bad English, it should be prime, thx for noticing